# The Chazon Ish pronunciation

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, chazzan-prayer-leader, agada-stories-legends, chazon-ish

The Chazon Ish would tell the *Shatz* to be careful pronouncing בַּֽעַל גְּבוּרוֹת so it didn't come out as בַּֽל. What is a source that the Chazon Ish would do this?

Comment: Common sense? Why would you think to say something heretical?

Comment: ba3al jaburoth?

Comment: *M'gilla* ([24b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=24b&format=text)): זיל אימא ליה כשאתה מגיע אצל וחכיתי לה' לא נמצאת מחרף ומגדף. Rashi (s.v. *lo*): שהיה קורא לחיתי"ן היהי"ן נראה כאומר והכיתי.

Comment: I agree that it's common sense. Is there any sefer in which the Chazon Ish discusses pronouncing or enunciating words properly?

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, while that is a perfectly acceptable pronunciation, the Chazon Ish would likely have held the Temani pronunciation invalid, much as he did the Polish pronunciation. Thus, knowing that he would not respond amen to any bracha in which the cholam of ה׳ were pronounced oy (וֹי) the correct pronunciation for him would be ba'al gevureis.

Comment: @noach He Definatly wouldn't hold it invalid for we all know there is a halocho to differentiate between an Alaf n 3ayeen. If he would say ba al instead of ba 3al he would be in the wrong and invalid himself

Comment: Also teimonim don't pronounce the 7olam as an oy but either an aw or eh

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt "he would not respond amen to any bracha in which the cholam of ה׳ were pronounced oy (וֹי)" do you have any sources for this ? Thanks

Comment: @Frank, the article on the pronunciation of said vowel in the forward to R' Wiesenthal's *Siddur Sefas Yisroel* (Opensiddur).

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt thanks, just read it and it is not exactly about all brachos and hashem name pronunciation, it is about the way the word "o-heiv" is said during hazara, here the quote : In the בית המדרש of the חזון איש, if aש"ץ  (in שמונה עשרה) ended the ברכה of השיבה שופטינו with"מלך אוֹיֵב צדקה ומשפט"  ( אוֹיֵבinstead of אוֹהֵב) - it is well known, (and brought in a number ofספרים ) that theחזון איש  would not answer אמן.

Comment: @Frank, I appear to have misremembered, although the article is a polemic against the "oy" pronunciation in general.

Answer (score 1):

Halacha Sefarim bring this down, including:

- The [Ben Ish Chai](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9_%D7%97%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA#.D7.94.D7.9C.D7.9B.D7.95.D7.AA):  וכשאומר בעל גבורות ידגיש העי"ן שלא יבולע ויהיה כאומר **בל גבורות** ח"ו וכנז' בחס"ל

Comment: if you were citing the Ben Ish Chai, how would you cite it as a sefer?

Comment: Seems that here's a Sefer by that name - a link in the heading of the page I linked to points to https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9_%D7%97%D7%99_(%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8) describing the Sefer Ben Ish Chai. בן איש חי הוא ספר דרשות לפי פרשיות השבוע, ובו ביאור על פרשת השבוע והלכות שחובר על ידי הרב יוסף חיים מבגדאד (1834–1909), לפי סדר דרשותיו של הרב לקהילתו בשבתות. הספר התקבל כספר הלכה קובע בחלק מקהילות המזרח התיכון ובעיקר על יהדות בבל.